# flatten results onto one line in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

[report example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzoEg.png)

i have a report that displays client contact details, but annoyingly for each different contact type it displays the results on a separate line! Can anyone advise if it possible to show the results on one line using an expression or some sort of filter, not using SQL.

as you can see from the image Miss S has both a mobile (MBL) and telephone (TEL) number but they show on different rows, if in my program i were to add an email address then it would add a third line, is it possible to flatten the results down to one row?

regards

Comment: You have not shown any images

Comment: thanks for pointing that out Alan - now updated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the Contact Type column from the tablix as this won't be valid once you put all the contact details on the same row.

Once this is removed, you will then need to edit the row group (under the main design window) and group by the first 5 columns only. There may already be grouping set, if so check that contact type is not in the group by list, if it is remove it.

---

**Alternative**

---

*After saying all this, I can't help but think this report would be a whole lot easier, assuming the data was structured correctly (it may already be), to use a matrix control. That way all this and the answer to your previous question (asked recently) would be automatic. I won't go into detail but if you are interested, create a new question and show the output from your dataset query, the query code itself and the desired output. optionally, accept this answer* ! :)